# How to execute function in background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, xcode6

I need execute the sessionVideo.startRunning() of AVFoundation in background to not get a freeze UI, but when I execute this in background I  can't save the video and I don't know why I can't.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
   self.sessionVideo.startRunning()
   var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(self.sessionVideo) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       previewLayer.frame = self.viewCamera.bounds
       self.viewCamera.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
   })
})
```

To record:

```
self.fileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(PathOfTheVideo) , recordingDelegate: self.delegate)
```

To stop and save:

```
func stop(){
 self.fileOutput.stopRecording()
    completion = {reason in println(reason)}

    library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(NSURL(PathOfTheVideo), completion)
 }
```

And when I try save this, this is nil.  How can do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/AVCam_AVCamViewController_m.htm . Use a DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL.

Comment: But... when can I use DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL if I use this in: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, 0), { I get an error 'dispatch_queue_attr_t' is not a subtype of 'NSNumber'

Comment: It's not a global queue. Look at the code referenced. You create a serial queue and then you use it.